# ASP.NET MVC dropdown-list from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Ok, so I'm new to this whole MVC-world, but it seems to be a pretty good way of getting things done and I'm trying to make it work here.

The problem is:
I can't get data from my table in my SQL-database to a simple drop-down form on my registration page.

I have just no idea where to put the stuff, where to code to open the table, select the ids, where to put the `response.write` and how do I send it to the view?

My Model is this:

```
    public class users
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int user_id {get; set;}
}
```

My Controller is this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And my View is this:

```
@model Community.Models.users
```

I have googled for 2 days now and watched several videos on youtube but of no use, I can't find it. Please, anyone with some knowledge here? And please point me to some good tutorials and/or forums where I can browse for more questions I might have

---

Still no luck on this project..

I'm creating a form and within that form, i want a db-loop (`IEnumerable`).. But the current model is not a `IEnumerable`. I'm pretty much stuck, watched a bunch of tutorials and they all just list ONE connection, what if I want two models?

Here is my Controller, I get that you must pass a list to the view, right?

```
    public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        return View(db.users.ToList());
    }
```

How do i get hold of that list in my view witout an `IEnumerable` model?

@neoistheone, your example didnt help me much, my DB opens like this:

```
private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
```

and i don't know how, but it opens the connection.
I've tried for so many hours now, its just silly, haven't slept for soo long!

I'm used to programming ASP-Classic fyi, and this is my first serious try to upgrade my knowledge about programing an up-to-date language and OOP.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396883/asp-net-mvc-populate-a-drop-down-list and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314933/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-pass-a-list-from-a-class-in-model-to-a-repeater-in-a-vie

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10018406/1241400

Answer (score 22):

Add the `SelectList` to your model:

```
public SelectList DropDownList { get; set; }
```

build the class for that collection:

```
public class MyListTable
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller, load the data for the `MyListTable` class from the database:

```
var list = new List<MyListTable>();

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT KeyField, DisplayField FROM Table", c))
{
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            list.Add(new MyListTable
            {
                Key = rdr.GetString(0),
                Display = rdr.GetString(1)
            });
        }
    }
}

var model = new users();
model.DropDownList = new SelectList(list, "Key", "Display");
```

and then finally, you need to send your model to the view:

```
return View(model);
```

Now in the Razor you can display this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.DropDownList);
```

You of course can name these things better names, but you get the idea.

Comment: This looks good, only, my connection to the database looks like this: using (var db = new communityContext()), and I have NO idea how to "SELECT  * FROM ......"

Comment: @Tobias, you don't have to connect to the database the same way I do. I'm just giving you an example. You're not going to be able to just copy and paste this solution, you'll have to fit it in of course, I'm not writing your software - just helping you with this issue - so there's no way the code will just **fit in.**

Comment: @Tobias, the same way you get all rows from any table using a `DbContext`. You access the property that's available for that table. Like I said, you need to fit this in. You might be able to get rid of the `MyListTable` class because you have a `DbContext`. You could send a `List` of those in to the `SelectList` class and use different key and display fields. Look up the API's and learn them, understand them at an abstract level.

Comment: I understand that, but the SQL-query you wrute.. How do i wrote it in my application, its not the way you did it. I guess I'm just stupid not to have figured it out yet.

Comment: +1 Great and detailed. I was trying everything to populate DDL and post selected value in Controller. All gone in vain until ur solution. Thanks man

Comment: @syedmohsin, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: I found this solution and have had a similar issue, but not sure this method will work for me because we use an Entity-Framework EDMX, so I don't think I can just manually add things to the model. Will this still work or do I need to try something completely different?

Comment: DOWNVOTE for the View, which is not accurate. Especially for a newbie expecting it to actually work. 
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOrderId, Model.DropDownList, "Select One");
The DropDownListFor requires at least 3 parameters, and the 1st one needs to be an Id indicating the select dropdown's Name or Value.

Answer (score 11):

There a great answers already but Here is another approach.

You will use `user` as a model, `ListUserViewModel` as view-model  and `UserController` as the contoller. The work of view-model is to carry all info needed to be displayed on the page from the controller without adding unwanted properties into the model class. In your case list of users from database into the drop down list.

Model:

```
public class User     //By the way use singular when naming a class
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int user_id {get; set;}
}
```

View-model

```
public class ListUserViewModel
{
    public list<User> Users{get; set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListUser()
    {
        var users = db.Users.ToList();

        var viewModel = new ListUserViewModel { Users = users };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Now use ListUserViewModel instead of User in your view as a model

```
@model Community.Models.ListUserViewModel
```

and the drop down

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Users, new SelectList(Model.Users, "user_id", "name"), " ")
```

Explanation:

You are creating drop down list for Users with `Model.Users` as select list data source. `"user_id"` as a value of the selected user and `"name"` as display label. the last argument( i put empty string `" "`) is a default value that the drop down will display before selection.

I hope this will help you or someone else.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

model

```
public string CoutryID { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
```

Controller method which fill the list

```
public List<Country> getCountryList()
        {
            using (QRMG_VendorPortalDataContext _context = new QRMG_VendorPortalDataContext())
            {
                return (from c in _context.Countries
                        where c.IsDeleted == false
                        select c).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Drop down list in View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CoutryID,
         new SelectList(Model.CountryList,
                        "CoutryID", "Value"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I find this system works (and avoids using ViewBag):

**View Model:**

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    // This could be string, int or Guid depending on what you need as the value
    public int YourDropdownSelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YourDropdownList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// Get database values (by whatever selection method is appropriate)
var dbValues = db.YourEntity.ToList();

// Make Selectlist, which is IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
var yourDropdownList = new SelectList(dbValues.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = item.YourSelectedDbText,
    Value = item.YourSelectedDbValue
}).ToList(), "Value", "Text");

// Assign the Selectlist to the View Model   
var viewModel = new YourViewModel(){
    // Optional: if you want a pre-selected value - remove this for no pre-selected value
    YourDropdownSelectedValue = dbValues.FirstOrDefault(),
    // The Dropdownlist values
    YourDropdownList = yourDropdownList
};

// return View with View Model
return View(viewModel);
```

**and in the View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.YourDropdownSelectedValue, Model.YourDropdownList, "select this text - change this to null to exclude", new { @class = "your-class" })
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are really new to ASP.Net MVC, this is a quite good Tutorial that shows you how the MVC-Pattern works.

MVC3: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3 
MVC4: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Here is the sample-code to download: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-MVC-3-10d1b098

this is an helpful video: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/conference-presentations/creating-nerddinnercom-with-microsoft-aspnet-model-view-controller-mvc

Answer (score 2):

this is my table in the database

[image]

take look it my Action controller

```
    // GET: Letters
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.LetterStatus = new SelectList(LetterStatusService.GetAllLettersStatus(), "Id", (CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture() == "ar") ? "NameArabic" : "Name", Request.QueryString["LetterStatus"]);
        return View();
    }
```

and in the view

```
  @Html.DropDownList("LetterStatus")
```

the constructor  I used is

```
new SelectList(
    list<Objlect> myListFromDatabase,
    string PropertyNameOfValueInHtml,
    string PropertyNameOfDesplayInHtml,
    string SelectedItemValue 
);
```

this line `Request.QueryString["LetterStatus"]` because I send the Selected Items within `QuerySrting`

and based on `CurrentCulture` I chose what column to display

and the result are [image]

but I think the best way to do this,,,, is to get or create the Items then Iterate throw them to generate the select tag manually. I described this approach well in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40447984/4251431)

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I had to put Everything together from about 5 different Stack Overflow entries. I'm a newbie that's not in love with EF. I prefer doing things in SQL. Mike Perrenoud got me started, but I had trouble getting his solution to compile properly in the view.

First, I declared my dropdown Id/Name inside my model and then declared a numeric selector plus a SelectList

```
        public class BusinessType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public int SelectedBusinessId { get; set; }
    public SelectList BusinessTypeddList { get; set; }
```

In my [HttpGet] (the one that does not pass in a model), I ALWAYS populate my dropdowns. I'm doing things in SQL Server because I find it easier than the EF abstraction and syntax (which baffles me). This code declares a List of business types and populates it directly from the database. Feel free to use a sproc or whatever. IMPORTANT: Don't forget to return the View(model) at the end or your View will get an object missing reference error.

```
            var list = new List<MerchantDetail.BusinessType>();

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(Common.DB_CONNECTION_STRING_BOARDING))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, BusinessTypeDesc as Name FROM BusinessType order by Id", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new MerchantDetail.BusinessType
                        {
                            Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                            Name = reader.GetString(1)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var model = new MerchantDetail();
        model.BusinessTypeddList = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name");
        model.SelectedBusinessId = 0;

        return View(model);
```

The view is simple. Mine looks like this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBusinessId, Model.BusinessTypeddList, "Select One:", new { @class = "custom-select" });
```

NOTE: Setting the SelectedBusinessId to 0 only works if there's nothing in the model. It will be set to one of the dropdown values otherwise. That will happen in a different HttpGet that passes the  model in.