# MVC populate dropdownlist from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to populate DropDownList from my database, but still have error

> Cannon implicity convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyWeb.Models.HomeViewModels.SelectListItem>'

My model:

```
 public class BazarInsertViewModel
        {           
            public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyCategory { get; set; }
        }
        public class SelectListItem
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```

and my controller:

```
public ActionResult BazarInsert()
        {
            var model = new Models.HomeViewModels.BazarInsertViewModel
            {
                MyCategory = GetCategory()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
  private IEnumerable<Models.HomeViewModels.SelectListItem> GetCategory()
        {
            var dbo = new WebEntities();
            var category = dbo
                        .bazar
                        .Select(x =>
                                new Models.HomeViewModels.SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                                    Text = x.TITLE
                                });

            return new SelectList(category, "Value", "Text");
        }
```

Please can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By returning `category.ToList()` it'll be fine. I'm using it in one of my projects and it works fine.

```
private IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> GetCategory()
{
    var dbo = new WebEntities();
    var category = dbo
                    .bazar
                    .Select(x =>
                            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                                Text = x.TITLE
                            });
     return category.ToList();
}
```

Comment: So is there other problem .. in view is `  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategoryId, new SelectList(Model.MyCategory, "Value", "Text"), "-----Select-----", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })` but still I have a error _Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items_

Comment: Use this instead... @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategoryId, Model.MyCategory, "-----Select-----", new { @class = "form-control" })

Answer (score 1):

Your method is `IEnumerable<Models.HomeViewModels.SelectListItem>` ! and your code returns `SelectList` `SelectList` cannot be converted to your custom `SelectListItem` class (without an explicit cast)

FYI : There is already a `SelectListItem` class in `System.Wb.Mvc`. Why not use that ?

```
private IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> GetCategory()
{
    var dbo = new WebEntities();
    var category = dbo
                    .bazar
                    .Select(x =>
                            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                                Text = x.TITLE
                            }).ToList();
     return category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass

```
  new SelectList(category.Select(x => new{Value=x.Value,Text=x.Text}).ToList(), "Value", "Text");
```

I give you just hint for initializing List but please to get object of class please write full class name.

Answer (score -1):

In GetCategory() you return a SelectList, but your method signature states IEnumerable.

Change your model property to a SelectList:

```
public class BazarInsertViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SelectList MyCategory { get; set; }
}
public class SelectListItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the method signature to return a SelectList

```
public ActionResult BazarInsert()
        {
            var model = new BazarInsertViewModel
            {
                MyCategory = GetCategory()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
        private SelectList GetCategory()
        {
            var dbo = new WebEntities();
            var category = dbo
                        .bazar
                        .Select(x =>
                                new Models.HomeViewModels.SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                                    Text = x.TITLE
                                });

            return new SelectList(category, "Value", "Text");
        }
```

Comment: He needs a IEnumerable of SelectList to use in a the Razor view. So it should be the other way around. He needs to return a list not a single item

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at  `GetCategory()` you are supposed to return a list of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Instead you are returning a single item of type `SelectList`.

If can change your code, check another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40075032/3222478) here or other approaches to almost similar question.

Comment: Put all relevant code in your answer please. Don't say the answer is here. If you beleiev this to be a duplicate flag it as such